# Why data is lost in kafka even with 'min.insync.replicas=2' and 'acks=all'

Tags: apache-kafka

Test case: 3 node kafka cluster, tested on 2.6.3. This exercise makes me wondering why we loose data while there is a possibility to have all the messages that were written with acks=all (and that is the whole point to have min.insync.replicas=2).

Let's setup some environment variables

```
export BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka171:9092,kafka172:9092,kafka173:9092
export TOPIC_NAME=playground__dummy_test
export ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zk:2181/kafka_123
```

Create topic

```
$ kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper $ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT --topic $TOPIC_NAME --create --partitions 1 --replication-factor 3
```

Check topic

```
$ kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper $ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT --describe --topic $TOPIC_NAME

Topic: playground__dummy_test   Partition: 0    Leader: 171 Replicas: 171,172,173   Isr: 171,172,173
```

Simple producer (I will mark '>' when I am producing to the topic)

```
$ kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list $BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS --topic $TOPIC_NAME --request-required-acks all
> I am writing to all 3 of you
```

Broker 171 shutdown

```
>everything should be fine now
>there is 171 broker down

Topic: playground__dummy_test   Partition: 0    Leader: 172 Replicas: 171,172,173   Isr: 173,172

> all I am writing is in 172,173
```

Broker 172 shutdown

```
Topic: playground__dummy_test   Partition: 0    Leader: 173 Replicas: 171,172,173   Isr: 173

> hey
NotEnoughReplicasException: Messages are rejected since there are fewer in-sync replicas than required.
```

That is understandable, that is what happens with 'min.insync.replicas=2' and 'acks=all'

Let's shutdown broker 173 (now all 3 brokers are lost)

Startup 171

```
Topic: playground__dummy_test   Partition: 0    Leader: -1  Replicas: 171,172,173   Isr: 173
```

Startup 172 (no change, still there is no leader as we have unclean.leader.election.enable=false')

```
Topic: playground__dummy_test   Partition: 0    Leader: -1  Replicas: 171,172,173   Isr: 173
```

We have two brokers running now, one down, recent data (the one that was written with acks=all is in 172 and 173)

Now let's assume that 173 is gone forever. We are running with 'unclean.leader.election.enable=false' so the only choice now is to allow unclean leader election.

Who is controller?

```
$ CONTROLLER_ID=`/opt/kafka/bin/zookeeper-shell.sh $ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT get /controller | grep brokerid | jq '.brokerid'`
```

Enable unclean election on controller

```
$ kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server $BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS --entity-type brokers --entity-name $CONTROLLER_ID --alter --add-config unclean.leader.election.enable=true 
Completed updating config for broker: 171.

$ kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper $ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT --describe --topic $TOPIC_NAME
Topic: playground__dummy_test   Partition: 0    Leader: 171 Replicas: 171,172,173   Isr: 171,172
-> so, election happened

$ kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server $BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS --topic $TOPIC_NAME --from-beginning
: I am writing to all 3 of you
```

That is all I can read from this topic, dataloss is there.

Why he could not choose the more recent replica?

Comment: exactly the same behaviour can be seen with apache kafka 3.3.1

Comment: Current implementation does not apply the logic of selecting a live replica with most data. It simples picks a live replica as the leader.